# Formatting string in java date

Tags: java, date-format

I have a String and it contains the value : `Wed Feb 22 17:38:38 GMT 2012`. How can i format the string so its `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: A simple search with term: "java format date" would have you provide a lot of useful link

Answer (score 4):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`. It can `parse` and `format` dates.

You can use one instance to parse one format, and another instance to format it to the desired output format.

Comment: `Date.parse` is deprecated. Use `DateFormat.parse` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't format the *string*. You can *parse* the string to some appropriate date-related type, and then format *that* value. So you'll need to work out two formats - the input for parsing, and the output for formatting. Look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) if you want to use `java.util.Date`/`Calendar`, or [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) (which is a much nicer date/time API).

Note that if you know the time zone specifier will *always* be "GMT", that makes life slightly simpler... you can just set the time zone of whatever parser you're using to UTC, and expect the literal value 'GMT' for that part of the input.